# Is there a way to prevent Guzzle from appending [] to field names with multiple values in a POST request?

Tags: php, post, guzzle

When using Guzzle to POST a field with multiple values, brackets get appended to the field names:

```
    <?php
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
        'base_uri' => 'https://www.example.com/test',
        'headers' => [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        ],
     );

    $client->request('POST', '', [
        'form_params' => [
            'foo' => [
                'hello',
                'world',
            ],
        ],
    ]);
```

Guzzle sends this data as `foo[0]=hello&foo[1]=world`. Is there a way to omit the brackets, so that the data is sent as `foo=hello&foo=world`? Google Forms, for example, returns a 400 error response if the brackets are included.

Comment: Have you tried `'form_params'=>['foo'=>'hello','foo'=>'world']`?

Comment: Yes, the problem with that is the resultant array will have a duplicate key `foo` and thus overwrite 'hello' with 'world', leaving only `['foo' => 'world']` for `form_params`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There currently is no way to achieve this by using the automatic encoding with `post_params`, so you'll have to provide your own raw POST body if you need this exact format.

Fortunately, there's a very helpful function in `GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Query` (which should automatically come installed if you required guzzle through composer), named `build`, which does exactly what you need.

```php
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Query;

$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'base_uri' => 'https://www.example.com/test',
    'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    ]
]);

$client->request('POST', '', [
    'body' => Query::build([
        'foo' => [
            'hello',
            'world',
        ],
    ]),
]);
```